# NodeJS Error The above error occurred in the <path> component

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs

This is my standard bootstrap code snippet.
I want to use the bootstrap menu
I had previously written these codes in PHP and I just started learning NodeJS and I want to implement it in NodeJS.

I create this function in  NodeJS

```
import React from 'react';

function PageHeader() {
    return <React.StrictMode>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
            <symbol id="home" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M8.354 1.146a.5.5 0 0 0-.708 0l-6 6A.5.5 0 0 0 1.5 7.5v7a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h4.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-4h2v4a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5H14a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-7a.5.5 0 0 0-.146-.354L13 5.793V2.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.293L8.354 1.146zM2.5 14V7.707l5.5-5.5 5.5 5.5V14H10v-4a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v4H2.5z"></path>
            </symbol>
            <symbol id="speedometer2" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V4.5A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4zM3.732 5.732a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l.915.914a.5.5 0 1 1-.708.708l-.914-.915a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.707zM2 10a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1.586a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H2.5A.5.5 0 0 1 2 10zm9.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H12a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm.754-4.246a.389.389 0 0 0-.527-.02L7.547 9.31a.91.91 0 1 0 1.302 1.258l3.434-4.297a.389.389 0 0 0-.029-.518z"></path>
                <path fillRule="evenodd" d="M0 10a8 8 0 1 1 15.547 2.661c-.442 1.253-1.845 1.602-2.932 1.25C11.309 13.488 9.475 13 8 13c-1.474 0-3.31.488-4.615.911-1.087.352-2.49.003-2.932-1.25A7.988 7.988 0 0 1 0 10zm8-7a7 7 0 0 0-6.603 9.329c.203.575.923.876 1.68.63C4.397 12.533 6.358 12 8 12s3.604.532 4.923.96c.757.245 1.477-.056 1.68-.631A7 7 0 0 0 8 3z"></path>
            </symbol>
            <symbol id="table" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M0 2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2zm15 2h-4v3h4V4zm0 4h-4v3h4V8zm0 4h-4v3h3a1 1 0 0 0 1-1v-2zm-5 3v-3H6v3h4zm-5 0v-3H1v2a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h3zm-4-4h4V8H1v3zm0-4h4V4H1v3zm5-3v3h4V4H6zm4 4H6v3h4V8z"></path>
            </symbol>
            <symbol id="people-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M11 6a3 3 0 1 1-6 0 3 3 0 0 1 6 0z"></path>
                <path fillRule="evenodd" d="M0 8a8 8 0 1 1 16 0A8 8 0 0 1 0 8zm8-7a7 7 0 0 0-5.468 11.37C3.242 11.226 4.805 10 8 10s4.757 1.225 5.468 2.37A7 7 0 0 0 8 1z"></path>
            </symbol>
            <symbol id="grid" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M1 2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 2.5 1h3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 7 2.5v3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 5.5 7h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1 5.5v-3zM2.5 2a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3zm6.5.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 10.5 1h3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 15 2.5v3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 13.5 7h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 9 5.5v-3zm1.5-.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3zM1 10.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 2.5 9h3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 7 10.5v3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 5.5 15h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1 13.5v-3zm1.5-.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3zm6.5.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 10.5 9h3a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.5 1.5v3a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 9 13.5v-3zm1.5-.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3z"></path>
            </symbol>
            <symbol id="logout" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M 74.163 0 l -7.07 7.071 l 3.892 3.892 h -9.455 C 49.658 10.963 40 20.622 40 32.493 v 18.713 h 10 V 32.493 c 0 -6.357 5.172 -11.53 11.529 -11.53 h 9.455 l -3.892 3.892 l 7.07 7.071 l 15.964 -15.963 L 74.163 0 z" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; strokeLinecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fillRule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform=" matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0) " strokeLinecap="round"></path>
                <path fillRule="evenodd" d="M 76.594 90 H 13.406 C 6.014 90 0 83.986 0 76.594 V 13.406 C 0 6.014 6.014 0 13.406 0 h 28.119 v 10 H 13.406 C 11.528 10 10 11.528 10 13.406 v 63.188 C 10 78.472 11.528 80 13.406 80 h 63.188 C 78.472 80 80 78.472 80 76.594 V 38.159 h 10 v 38.435 C 90 83.986 83.986 90 76.594 90 z" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; strokeLinecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fillRule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform=" matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0) " strokeLinecap="round"></path>
            </symbol>
        </svg>

        <header>
            <div className="px-3 py-2 bg-dark text-white">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
                        <a href="/" className="d-flex align-items-center my-2 my-lg-0 me-lg-auto text-white text-decoration-none">
                            <img src="img/zig210-90.png" style="width: 185px;" alt="logo" />
                        </a>

                        <ul className="nav col-12 col-lg-auto my-2 justify-content-center my-md-0 text-small">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" className="nav-link text-secondary">
                                    <svg className="bi d-block mx-auto mb-1" width="24" height="24" style="fill: white;">
                                        <use xlinkHref="#home"></use>
                                    </svg>
                                    home
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" className="nav-link text-white">
                                    <svg className="bi d-block mx-auto mb-1" width="24" height="24" style="fill: white;">
                                        <use xlinkHref="#speedometer2"></use>
                                    </svg>
                                    Desk
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" className="nav-link text-white">
                                    <svg className="bi d-block mx-auto mb-1" width="24" height="24" style="fill: white;">
                                        <use xlinkHref="#table"></use>
                                    </svg>
                                    table
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" className="nav-link text-white">
                                    <svg className="bi d-block mx-auto mb-1" width="24" height="24" style="fill: white;">
                                        <use xlinkHref="#grid"></use>
                                    </svg>
                                    grid
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" className="nav-link text-white">
                                    <svg className="bi d-block mx-auto mb-1" width="24" height="24" style="fill: white;">
                                        <use xlinkHref="#people-circle"></use>
                                    </svg>
                                    people
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="logout.php" className="nav-link text-white">
                                    <svg className="bi d-block mx-auto mb-1" width="24" height="24" style="fill: white;">
                                        <use xlinkHref="#logout"></use>
                                    </svg>
                                    logout
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </React.StrictMode>;
}

export default PageHeader;
```

When I run it, it shows these errors

```
The above error occurred in the <path> component:

    at path
    at symbol
    at svg
    at PageHeader
    at App

react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <img> component:

    at img
    at a
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at header
    at PageHeader
    at App


6react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <svg> component:

    at svg
    at a
    at li
    at ul
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at header
    at PageHeader
    at App
```

How do I fix the errors?

Unfortunately, this framework does not have enough documentation and everything is changing. In addition to looking for a solution to my problems, I would like to know why it is popular.

[image]

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: The above error occurred in the <path> component:

Comment: Yes, so what is the error? Does it not tell you?

Comment: No, Chrome displays these in the console. And the html page is empty, I have added a screenshot above

Comment: I noticed some problems and fixed them, for example, I fixed the style.
convert style="display: none;" to style={{display: 'none;'}}. However, some bugs have been fixed, but some remain.  react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Style property values shouldn't contain a semicolon. Try "display: none" instead.
    at svg
    at PageHeader
    at App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the stolen tag
After seeing the link below, I made changes in the HTML code that fixed the bugs.
https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_css_styling.asp

For example, as follows:
‍‍‍

```
‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍const svgStyle = {
    display: "none"
};

function PageHeader() {
    return <React.StrictMode>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style={svgStyle}>
```